# ASP.Net SignalR: http://127.0.0.1/signalr/hubs (404 Not found) when accessed from different application

Tags: signalr

I have created a simple chat application following the [Getting Started With SignalR](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/getting-started-with-signalr-20/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr-20) URL. When I run and test the program it is working wonderfully fine.

I tried to create a simple client out of this application with a simple HTML and required SignalR.JS package installed as instructed in the second part of [Self Hosting SignalR](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/getting-started-with-signalr-20/tutorial-signalr-20-self-host) the article where a html and set of JS files try to access the chat application hosted in IIS (one developed following the Getting Started URL.

I am getting the signalr/hubs 404 Not Found error when firebug is used to trace and is not working. Can someone please help me understand what change we need to do to get the chat server working from the JavaScript (and any other) client application.

My chat server is hosted in my IIS as srserver (virtual directory) and the client again is hosted in IIS as srclient (virtual directory) . It is not Cross domain but still not able to get this working.

Comment: Are you actually self hosting, or did you just use the JS portions of the self hosting article to connect the IIS srserver? If you already have the chat application from "Getting Started With SignalR" working, why not use that as your srserver and just remove the html/css/js/etc... and copy it over to the srcsclient?

Comment: Yes I am able to get this done and it is working fine now. As Gortler suggested the generate proxy and implement process solved the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had similar problem , that i was missing in the auto generated hubs js (visual studio generates it automatically but when in production environment i had to place it there)

you can generate it using the following command, and than place in the production environment :
signalr ghp /path:[path to the .dll that contains your Hub class]

follow the full instrutinos [here](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/hubs-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client#clientsetup)

Comment: Thanks Gortler, what if the client javascript is part of the web application that is developed in Java (they don't understand .dll) and if it is some smart app environment. I am not sure if I am missing something very simple here, but couldn't proceed.